# How long must I sample for in order to ensure with high confidence that all events with probability $>p$ were seen?

Tags: probability, sampling

Assume that you have a big urn filled with many balls of different colors. The total number of balls/distinct colors is unknown, as well as the probability of each color. How many samples (with replacement) should you take in order to ensure, with high confidence, that you've seen all colors that appear with probability equal or higher than a value $p$?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing $k$ to $p$, which is much more intuitive for a probability ($k$ rather suggests an integer number).

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @Stephan No, the question popped up in my mind while I was thinking about the optimal stopping criteria for a Program Analysis algorithm I'm working on. I wouldn't be surprised if a similar question appears in a textbook, however, and would appreciate a reference to it if that's the case.